# Is there a way to make an iOS device brick itself every 2 hours?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to limit the amount of time my kids can play on their iPad. Sure there is guided access mode and other solutions out there but here's what I really want:

I hand the iPad to kid with no password on it, he can unlock and watch or play for 2 hours, then, without warning the device goes all black and shuts off complete for 2 hours before it boots up again.

i.e. forcing the kid to go outside and play before he can be an ipad junkie again.

With the other solutions I've read about I need to either:

1. unlock the iPad first and set time limit each and every time I hand it to kid
2. somehow protect the password I used to login and not let kid just factory reset the iPad.

I'm looking for this way at the firmware level (maybe with jailbreaking) to make this every 2 hour thing is just part of the device.

Comment: If you brick the device, then the device cannot be used again, plus this isn’t possible on iOS

Comment: You want to lock the device down so they can't change anything but "somehow" protecting your own password is a challenge? I don't think anything is going to help. Except perhaps hide all the chargers in your home and give the devices to them with only enough power to last approximately two hours.

Comment: Uhh nope, to brick it it has to be wiped, which means no software is running which means the iPad doesn't know the time and can't stay bricked for 2 hours.. this is also a parenting question, not a technology one. By the time you are trying to make devices turn themselves off, I'm sorry to say, you're running around trying to deal with effects, not causes. Even if you could do this, if you don't address how your kid deals with technology vs being social in a different way, you'll just be back in a few days with a new problem. Not a dad, maybe I shouldn't speak to that, but I see it a lot.

Comment: It may be easier to just take it from him and then lock it away until you're ready for him to have it. You can also add restrictions (with a passcode) to prevent access to certain things but if you forget the restrictions code you'll have to erase the iPad. Taking it away from him might be best.

Comment: I heard a radio program about obesity in kids (no implication here however) but the conclusion is relevant : “to make a difference, parents have to get off the sofa”, so take him out and do things or are you giving him the ipad to have “me” time...